# wxCheckListBox update choices

Tags: python, wxwidgets

How to update/change the choice list of a wxCheckListBox on the fly? IN the reference http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_check_list_box.html#a7ef1af0cad44ed9b4ab99daa3469e10b I just can set this on the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wx.CheckListBox()  is variant of (inherits) wx.ListBox(), therefore you can see the docs for
wx.ListBox() and use data manipulation methods from there.

To add/delete items on the fly you would use:

```
lb = wx.CheckListBox(self, ...)
# Methods:
lb.Append()
lb.Insert()
lb.Delete()
```

And there are more. As I said, go and dig through docs for wx.ListBox().

Answer (score 0):

@hildogjr, you probably need to process wxEVT_CHECKLISTBOX